# How to find common data in replicates?

Tags: r

I have three .csv files and each files first column is Gene identification numbers (AGI: my experimental targets). the three files consisted with different experimental out comes. i.e. first file 250 targets, second ~500, and third ~ 2000.

Each file consisted with other information for the identified targets, e.g.
[image]

I want to identify common targets (AGIs) in these three .csv files and make a new working table combining other details of the common AGIs.

How can I identify the common targets (AGIs) using R programming?

Comment: Please don't post your data as an screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
# Read in CSV files and store in list
csv_filenames <- c("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv")
lst <- lapply(csv_filenames, read.csv)

# Return the intersect of AGI entries across all data.frames in the list
ovlp <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(lst, function(x) x$AGI))
```

`ovlp` is a `vector` with `AGI` IDs that are present in all CSV files; it's then easy to pull out relevant entries from the individual `data.frame`s by `match`ing `AGI` entries from `ovlp` with those from the `data.frame`s in the `list`.

---

To give a more explicit example, let's generate some fake data

```
set.seed(2017);
lst <- list(
    data.frame(AGI = letters[1:10], value = runif(10)),
    data.frame(AGI = letters[4:13], value = runif(10)),
    data.frame(AGI = letters[8:17], value = runif(10)));
```

Then

```
ovlp <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(lst, function(x) x$AGI));
ovlp;
#[1] "h" "i" "j"
```

The entries in `ovlp` are those `AGI` entries that are present in all three `data.frame`s in `lst`.

---

An alternative approach could be to `merge` data from all `data.frame`s, and then filter rows based on the absence/presence of entries across all `data.frame`s.

---

### Update

In response to your comment, here is something that should get you started.

First off, let's join the `data.frame`s in the `list` based on the `"AGI"` values in a merged `data.frame` called `df`.

```
df <- Reduce(function(x, y) dplyr::full_join(x, y, by = "AGI"), lst);
```

Let's take a look at the merged `data.frame`

```
df;
#    AGI    value.x     value.y      value
#1    a 0.92424261          NA         NA
#2    b 0.53717641          NA         NA
#3    c 0.46919565          NA         NA
#4    d 0.28862618 0.674331481         NA
#5    e 0.77008816 0.002020766         NA
#6    f 0.77276871 0.025093514         NA
#7    g 0.03932234 0.432077786         NA
#8    h 0.43490560 0.499391912 0.63411352
#9    i 0.47216639 0.388681932 0.37986744
#10   j 0.27383312 0.395375316 0.94207403
#11   k         NA 0.715707325 0.75499369
#12   l         NA 0.940999879 0.22761184
#13   m         NA 0.827229161 0.91466603
#14   n         NA          NA 0.62044504
#15   o         NA          NA 0.31910458
#16   p         NA          NA 0.07628881
#17   q         NA          NA 0.26083932
```

We can now select rows that are "complete" (i.e. have values from all three `data.frame`) and then average values for every `AGI`.

```
library(tidyverse);
df[complete.cases(df), ] %>%
    gather(key, value, -AGI) %>%
    group_by(AGI) %>%
    summarise(value.mean = mean(value))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  AGI   value.mean
#  <chr>      <dbl>
#1 h          0.523
#2 i          0.414
#3 j          0.537
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Evers,

This is gonna helpful for me. 
It’s great you are bio-informatician and I can explain well. 
These three .csv files are results of three replicates of one experiment. So my aim is filter the common AGIs in three .CSV files and average the ria data for each AGIs.
What my final average O/P should look like is
AGI (express in all 3 reps) and average ria (of three reps)

Comment: You're very welcome @Oncidium; I've included an update to address the problem statement in your comment. The general idea is to merge the data, select "complete" rows (where we have data from all three data sets), and then calculate some summary statistic(s) (here the mean). This should get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. Great help :) Appreciate.